# How to decompress jsonlz4 files (Firefox bookmark backups) using the command line?

Tags: firefox, compression, json, lz4

There seems to be various JavaScript+browser specific ways of decompressing this, but isn't there some way to transform jsonlz4 files to something `unlz4` will read?

Comment: Cross reference: [Reading "jsonlz4" bookmarkbackup files • mozillaZine Forums](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=2885435) (2014-11-04)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I was able to unpack the jsonlz4 by using [`lz4json`](https://github.com/andikleen/lz4json):

```
apt-get install liblz4-dev
git clone https://github.com/andikleen/lz4json.git
cd lz4json
make
./lz4jsoncat ~/.mozilla/firefox/*/bookmarkbackups/*.jsonlz4
```

Comment: The andikleen solution is also good for `.json.mozlz4` files e.g. as shown at https://github.com/andikleen/lz4json/issues/1#issuecomment-336729026 (note to self: remember, remember, `gmake` on FreeBSD …).

Comment: Also: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1209390#c4 (2016-05-13) under Mozilla bug _1209390 - Use standard lz4 file format instead of the non-standard jsonlz4/mozlz4_ draws attention to [avih/dejsonlz4: Decompress Mozilla Firefox bookmarks backup files](https://github.com/avih/dejsonlz4)

Comment: FWIW, andikleen's tool failed to compile, with the error "undefined reference to LZ4_decompress_safe_partial" (I did install `liblz4-dev` prior to building it). avih's tool, OTOH, worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Isn't it ironic that an open-web org is using a proprietary compression format for user's data, making it non-trivial to examine your own data?!

Comment: @Graham-Perrin : [dejsonlz4](https://github.com/avih/dejsonlz4) worked very well for me. It doesn't "_transform jsonlz4 files to something unlz4 will read_" as requested but directly decompresses them. It would be good to make it a real answer to make it more visible.

Comment: I hope the Mozilla developers will soon get rid of LZ4 garbage.

Comment: This tool upstream doesn't work on ANY non-Linux system, I've forked it and fixed compilation issues on Mac OS X w/ MacPorts, as well as FreeBSD and NetBSD; if anyone wants to add and test support for any other system, let me know!  https://github.com/cnst/lz4json; the author rejected my pull request, because he's only interested in GNU/Linux support, apparently.

Comment: This tool is available for Ubuntu as `lz4json`. Install using `apt` or whatever software store you use.

Comment: you say you used `lz4json` to resolve that, but you clearly installed `liblz4-dev`

Answer (score 28):

Save this script in a file, e.g., `mozlz4`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from sys import stdin, stdout, argv, stderr
import os
try:
    import lz4.block as lz4
except ImportError:
    import lz4

stdin = os.fdopen(stdin.fileno(), 'rb')
stdout = os.fdopen(stdout.fileno(), 'wb')

if argv[1:] == ['-c']:
    stdout.write(b'mozLz40\0' + lz4.compress(stdin.read()))
elif argv[1:] == ['-d']:
    assert stdin.read(8) == b'mozLz40\0'
    stdout.write(lz4.decompress(stdin.read()))
else:
    stderr.write('Usage: %s -c|-d < infile > outfile\n' % argv[0])
    stderr.write('Compress or decompress Mozilla-flavor LZ4 files.\n\n')
    stderr.write('Examples:\n')
    stderr.write('\t%s -d < infile.json.mozlz4 > outfile.json\n' % argv[0])
    stderr.write('\t%s -c < infile.json > outfile.json.mozlz4\n' % argv[0])
    exit(1)
```

Comment: I had to change `import lz4` to `import lz4.block as lz4`, but it still didn't work. Some bytes vs string related error. OTOH this script worked with the import change: https://gist.github.com/Tblue/62ff47bef7f894e92ed5

Comment: @user31389: I updated the script. Does it work now?

Comment: Wasn't working for me until I did `$ pip install lz4`.

Comment: in macOS, I tried to install lz4 by installing pip from homebrew first, to no avail

Comment: Could you please explain why you are doing what you are doing in the script (maybe add explaining comments)? What is the line `stdout.write(b'mozLz40\0' + lz4.compress(stdin.read()))` doing? It looks like it is compressing something rather than decompression; why do you do that when the goal was to decompress jsonlz4 files?

Comment: Replying to above, based on the code that line indeed compresses. Run with `-c` to compress, `-d` to decompress. Also, `'mozlz40\0'` is simply a header that Mozilla uses; must be discarded during decompression or added during compression to Mozilla format.

Answer (score 10):

There are now simpler solutions for both Linux and Windows, with command-line programs to decompress these annoying `.jsonlz4` or `.mozlz4` files.

For **Debian/Ubuntu**, there is now the [`lz4json` package](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/lz4json):

```
sudo apt install lz4 lz4json
```

It provides `lz4jsoncat` :

> NAME
>
> lz4jsoncat - decompress tool for mozilla lz4json format
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> lz4jsoncat somefile.mozlz4 > somefile.json
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> lz4jsoncat can unpack lz4json files as generated by Firefox's bookmark backups and session restore.  The data is dumped to stdout.

For **Windows** (or Linux), there is also [mozlz4](https://github.com/jusw85/mozlz4). There are binaries available at the [releases page](https://github.com/jusw85/mozlz4/releases).

Comment: I think `lz4json` is enough. I don't have `lz4` installed and `lz4jsoncat` still decompresses the file.

Comment: @Daniel: yes, it seems that `lz4json` depends on `liblz4` anyway, at least in Debian/Ubuntu. So that should be enough.

Answer (score 8):

Sufficiently persistent Googling for this turns up a lot of solutions, but most of them seem to be either (a) broken by subsequent changes to underlying libraries, or (b) unnecessarily complex (at least to my personal taste), making them clunky to drop into existing code.

The following appears to work at least on Python 2.7 and 3.6 using a recent version of the [Python LZ4 bindings](https://pypi.org/project/lz4/):

```py
def mozlz4_to_text(filepath):
    # Given the path to a "mozlz4", "jsonlz4", "baklz4" etc. file, 
    # return the uncompressed text.
    import lz4.block
    bytestream = open(filepath, "rb")
    bytestream.read(8)  # skip past the b"mozLz40\0" header
    valid_bytes = bytestream.read()
    text = lz4.block.decompress(valid_bytes)
    return text
```

Of course this does not attempt to validate inputs (or outputs), is not intended to be secure, etc., but if one just wants to be able to parse one's own FF data, it gets the basic job done.

Command line version [here](https://gist.github.com/snorey/3eaa683d43b0e08057a82cf776fd7d83), which could be saved in the relevant directory and invoked from the command line as:

```bash
chmod +x mozlz4.py
./mozlz4.py <file you want to read> <file to save output to>
```

Answer (score 6):

Actually almost all Firefox profile **lz4** files are **mozlz4** files. It means they have the same "file format header".
Except one file. I talk about **webext.sc.lz4** file. It has `mozJSSCLz40v001\0` file header and maybe some `sc` packaging to pack group of files to on byte stream.

There is a Firefox addon to read or compress **.mozlz4** text files [mozlz4-edit](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/mozlz4-edit/)

Comment: It does have a different header, but the format's the same: magic (this time it's 15 characters not 8)+extracted size in 4 bytes LE (uint32). It's not "some sc packaging", but a startup cache file for the extensions installed in the browser (sc=startup cache). I don't think it's good for anything other than forensic use. You can check the original Mozilla code here: https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/09a4282d1172

Answer (score 4):

The accepted solution doesn't work on any non-Linux systems; I forked to https://github.com/cnst/lz4json to make it compile cleanly on all other UNIX® systems, including the BSDs; here's a sample for Mac OS X:

## Mac OS X UNIX® w/ MacPorts

```
sudo port install lz4
git clone https://github.com/cnst/lz4json.git
cd lz4json
make
./lz4jsoncat ~/Library/Application\ Support/Firefox/Profiles/CHANGE\
THIS.default/sessionstore-backups/recovery.jsonlz4 \
| python -m json.tool | fgrep :textarea | more
```

---

I also fixed compilation issues on ***FreeBSD*** and ***NetBSD*** w/ ***pkgsrc*** at https://github.com/cnst/lz4json; adding support for other systems like Fink or Homebrew would be trivial in my version, too; I welcome pull requests for any other UNIX systems (the author of the original tool is only interested in GNU/Linux support, refusing a pull request to add non-Linux support).

---

Also, here's the solution that's using Firefox directly: https://superuser.com/a/1363748/180573.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3 solution.
Needs lz4: `pip install lz4`

Save the code as .py file. Then you can drag & drop files on it or use the command line to access it.

It only accepts one file path. If that file has a Mozilla LZ4 extension (.lz4, .mozlz4, .jsonlz4, .baklz4) it will decode, otherwise it will try to encode the file (always to the same folder the original file was in). You will get an overwrite warning/question in case the output file already exists.

```
from sys import argv, exit
import os

try:
    import lz4.block as lz4
except ImportError:
    print("Please install lz4 via   'pip install lz4'.")


EXTENSIONS = {"1": ".lz4", "2": ".mozlz4", "3": ".jsonlz4", "4": ".baklz4"}



def check_overwrite(path):
    if os.path.exists(path):
        i = input(f"File {path} already exists. Overwrite? y/n\n")
        if i.lower() == "y":
            print("Overwriting file.")
            return True
        else:
            print("Exiting.")
            exit(1)
    else:
        return True


def print_info():
    print(f"Usage: {argv[0]} <infile>")
    print("Decompress Mozilla-LZ4 encoded <infile> or compress <infile> to Mozilla-LZ4.")
    print("Output file will be put in same folder as input file.")
    exit(1)


def choose_ext():
    print(f"Please choose file extension:")
    for k, v in EXTENSIONS.items():
        print(f"{k}: {v}")
    if (i := input()) in EXTENSIONS.keys():
        return EXTENSIONS[i]
    else:
        print("Invalid extension.\nExiting")
        exit(1)


def main():
    if len(argv) != 2:
        print_info()

    else:
        if not os.path.exists(argv[1]):
            print_info()
        else:
            in_full_name = os.path.basename(argv[1])
            in_folder_path = os.path.dirname(argv[1])
            in_name, in_ext = os.path.splitext(argv[1])  # "search.json", ".mozlz4"
            in_file_handle = open(argv[1], "rb")

            if in_ext.lower() in EXTENSIONS.values():
                ''' Decompress '''
                print(f"Trying to decompress {in_full_name}")
                out_file = os.path.join(in_folder_path, f"{in_name}")
                if check_overwrite(out_file):
                    with open(out_file, "wb") as f:
                        assert in_file_handle.read(8) == b"mozLz40\0"
                        f.write(lz4.decompress(in_file_handle.read()))

            else:
                ''' Compress '''
                print(f"Trying to compress {in_full_name}")
                ext = choose_ext()
                out_file = os.path.join(in_folder_path, f"{in_full_name}{ext}")
                if check_overwrite(out_file):
                    with open(out_file, "wb") as f:
                        f.write(b"mozLz40\0" + lz4.compress(in_file_handle.read()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```